# Socket.io Chat on Dreamhost: Hiding the URL

Tags: node.js, socket.io, dreamhost

My socket.io chat is accessible through the URL http://example.com:8080/. Dreamhost does not allow us to bind 80, so I am binding it on 8080.

I wanted to get rid of the port number in the URL. So, I used Dreamhost's Proxy Server feature (http://wiki.dreamhost.com/Proxy_Server), which is Apache's mod_proxy.

I proxied the port number 8080 to the URL http://example.com/socketchat. When I go to that URL, the chat does not work. I get this error:

"Proxy Error
The proxy server received an invalid response from an upstream server.
The proxy server could not handle the request GET /socket/.
Reason: Error reading from remote server"

Is there a way to get rid of the port number in the URL that works with socket.io? If nothing works, would it be a security risk if I leave the port number in the URL when I launch my website to the public? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Whether Apache quickly becomes a bottleneck or not depends on how you're using it exactly. It's a very mature web server and is hosting massive websites around the world just fine. Regardless, your socket.io application doesn't necessarily have to share the same port as your web application. You could have socket.io listen on port 8081, and have your normal http requests on port 8080. Then you would setup your proxy to point to 8080 as you have it now, and just have your socket.io connection go to 8081.

The port in this case shouldn't be a problem as it's not something a user would see in their URL, and the socket.io communication wouldn't have to go through the proxy. If you're serving enough requests for Apache to legitimately be a bottleneck, you should be able to spring for a better hosting environment anyway!

**Example**

**Server**

```
var app = require('http').createServer(handler)
  , io = require('socket.io').listen(8081)
  , fs = require('fs')

app.listen(8080);

function handler (req, res) {
  fs.readFile(__dirname + '/index.html',
  function (err, data) {
    if (err) {
      res.writeHead(500);
      return res.end('Error loading index.html');
    }

    res.writeHead(200);
    res.end(data);
  });
}

io.sockets.on('connection', function (socket) {
  socket.emit('news', { hello: 'world' });
  socket.on('my other event', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
  });
});
```

Notice that the webserver is listening on a separate port than the socket.io connection. This means you can safely proxy the normal http requests from 80 to 8080 using mod_proxy, and socket.io can communicate quite happily on port 8081 directly, bypassing the proxy. Your users will not have to type in a port in order to get to the site.

**Client**

```
<script src="http://domain.com:8081/socket.io/socket.io.js"></script>
<script>
  var socket = io.connect('http://domain.com:8081');
  socket.on('news', function (data) {
    console.log(data);
    socket.emit('my other event', { my: 'data' });
  });
</script>
```

Comment: Sorry I am very new to server side stuff and node.js/socket.io, still learning the ropes as I study examples/demos. Right now I am able to access the chat by going to example.com:8080 in my browser. How do I make it so I can just go to example.com/chat to get to the chat? Without having to bind port 80 (because Dreamhost don't allow it). I tried using mod_proxy (provided by Dreamhost) but that doesn't work. Is there another proxy that works with websockets that I can use? Thanks a million.

Comment: How is your server setup? How are you serving the web files? What I'm suggesting is having your node application create an http server listening on port 8080, and you map that to 80 using mod_proxy. Then you have you socket.io application listen on 8081, and you just point your javascript to that service. I've updated my answer to include an example of what I mean.

Comment: I think I am still too inexperienced to adequately answer your questions. (probably won't know what I am talking about) However, I read through your suggestion, example code and explanation, and I think I understand the general solution. I am going to study some more tutorials, and then your example. Thank you for pointing me in the right direction! :)

Answer (score 0):

My guess is that mod_proxy doesn't deal well with websockets, which is hardly surprising. That said, you really shouldn't put node.js behind Apache, as that defeats a lot of the purpose of node.js. Apache will quickly become your bottleneck.

Finally, no, there is no security risk with having socket.io on another port -- any security risk would be present regardless of which port you run it on. You might run into trouble with other firewalls, if they block connections to ports other than port 80 (which is not unheard of) -- but then again, such firewalls might present issues with websockets in any case.

Comment: I have no choice because Dreamhost does not allow us to bind to 80.

What I meant to ask is: if I give out the link to my website as "http://example.com:8080/", with the port number in the URL, would there be security issues? People would know I am using port 8080, would that be a hazard?

Sorry if I am not very clear, I am new to server side stuff.

Comment: Sorry if I wasn't clear: No, there is no security risk with exposing which port you run socket.io under.

Comment: Oh alright. I'm sorry I can't tick two answers. But I really appreciate your input. Thanks!